# ¿Cambiar un Textbox desde thread y clase externa? C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo que hacer un programa que revise si X cosas están activas, haciendo consultas a una base de datos y las muestre en un form.

Es algo de este estilo más o menos.

> Nota: Omito algunas partes del código ya que creo que no son necesarias para el entendimiento del mismo o la resolución del problema.

```
 _____________________________________
|_____________________________________|
|  Algo       |  Estado = activo      |
| Otra cosa   |  Estado = Pausado     |
| Y algo      |  Estado = Suspendido  |
|____ ______ ____________ ____________|
```

La cosa es que yo quiero controlar lo que aparezca en este formulario, los estados, desde un thread que hay en una clase distinta, es decir, el programa hará más cosas a parte de esto y me interesa dividirlo por clases y demás.

El problema surge cuando tengo que acceder desde el thread, que en sí, es un método estático. Esta es la idea que tenía, adjunto un ejemplo de las dos clases.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
{    
     public Form1(){
          InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void controlItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            //Iniciamos el hilo padre.
            Thread principal = new Thread(Hilos.mainthread);
            principal.Start();
      }
}
```

---

```
class Hilos
    {

        static MySqlConnection conn;
        private Boolean error;


        public static void mainthread() {



            //Creamos la conexión con la BBDD
            string myConnectionString = "server=xx.xx.xx.xx;uid=xxxxx;" +
                                        "pwd=xxxxxx*;database=xxxxxx";

            //Intentamos la conexión

            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            conn.Open();


            data=//Aquí iría una consulta MySQL

            if(data==xxxx){
              //Lo que quiero hacer es Form1.textbox1.text=Activo
              //Evento o algo para hacer que funcione

            }else if(data==yyyy){
              //Lo que quiero hacer es Form1.textbox1.text=Suspendido   
              //Evento o algo para hacer que funcione

            }else{
              //Lo que quiero hacer es Form1.textbox1.text=Pausado
              //Evento o algo para hacer que funcione

            }                

     }

}
```

Entonces, una vez expuesto el código lo que quiero saber es, como puedo hacer que cuando una de las condiciones se cumpla se lance un evento o algo (desconozco aún tema de eventos), para poder cambiar la Textbox correspondiente.

Comment: "y me interesa dividirlo por clases y demás." y que tienen que ver los threads en eso.. un acceso a base de datos no deberia ir en otro thread.. La pregunta es buena.. podrias explicar un poco mas, que estas buscando con separar el sistema en threads?

Comment: La cosa es, que este programa tendrá una clase para hacer consultas a una BBDD, otra clase hará comprobaciones mediante última fecha de modificación de X archivo, y quiero dividirlo por clases para que sea más claro. El proyecto aún no ha cobrado una forma, así que todavía estoy pensando en alternativas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aunque hay formas de hacer lo que pides y de la forma cómo lo pides, el patrón que se recomienda es el de no hacer trabajo de UI en el método que hace las consultas a la base de datos.

Mas bien, es mejor dividir las responsabilidades de forma que tu método que trabaja con la base de datos simplemente devuelve un valor que luego el consumidor se encarga de asignar a un control en el UI.

Y asumo que tu deseo de usar un thread para el trabajo con la base de datos es para que el UI thread se desocupe mientras la consulta se efectúa. De ser el caso, en vez de trabajar con un thread directamente, hoy se recomienda usar un `Task` en conjunto con `async/await`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo estructurarlo:

```
private async void controlItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => ObtenerEstado());
}

private string ObtenerEstado()
{
    // hacer consulta a la base de datos

    if (data==xxxx)
    {
        return "Activo";
    }
    else if (data==yyyy)
    {
        return "Suspendido";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Pausado";
    } 
}
```

Vale la pena mencionar también que, dependiendo de la librería que empleas para hacer la consulta a la base de datos, puede que esta ya incluya métodos asíncronos. De ser el caso, no sería necesario el `Task`.

Comment: ¿No se me quedaría el programa colgado si hago eso? La cosa es que tiene que haber un hilo en segundo plano actualizando la textbox en tiempo real.

Comment: El `Task.Run()` trabaja en un hilo en segundo plano. Y cuando este termina su ejecución, todo lo que le sigue al `await` vuelve a ejecutarse en el hilo principal, lo que incluye la asignación al textbox.  De modo que si tu pregunta es si el programa va a quedar colgado miestras ejecuta el método `ObtenerEstado`, la respuesta es no. Pero te sugiero de probarlo.

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido, aunque no se si es algo correcto o una solución válida añadir una clase que haga entre "conexión", getEstado setEstado y desde un timer, cada 10 segundos por ejemplo, cambiar el estado....

Comment: En efecto. Si usas un `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, entonces el código sería idéntico a lo que te dejé, con la diferencia que en vez de un `controlItem_Click`, el event handler sería `timer1_Tick` o algo así. Pero el punto es que, de una forma u otra, trata de separar las responsabilidades de forma que el trabajo de UI no quede mezclado con la capa de acceso a los datos.

Comment: @Aritzbn yo te recomendaría hacer caso a la solución propuesta aqui. El trabajo con la clase `Thread` está desaconsejado desde hace mucho, la forma moderna y correcta de hacerlo es usar `Task`, y como ves en el ejemplo propuesto, es muy sencillo de manejar.

Comment: @sstan ¿Que significa lo de ' textbox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => ObtenerEstado()); '  ¿Que sentido tiene aquí el operador =>?

Comment: `() => ObtenerEstado()` es una expresión lambda, que básicamente es una forma de expresar una función de forma compacta y sin tener que definirla separadamente. Es un aspecto del lenguaje C# que se usa mucho, sobre todo en conjunto con LINQ. Si no estás familiarizado con ella, vale la pena que leas al respecto aquí: [Expresiones lambda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Leere sobre ellas, ya que soy bastante novato en esto de C#, principalmente o hasta ahora he realizado mis estudios viendo casi todo en java. De todas formas, sería mucho problema responder en un comentario un equivalenete con expresiones más comunes?

Comment: Ah muy bien. De hecho, en la última versión de Java, también existen las expresiones lambda. En todo caso, tanto con el tema de los lambda, los Tasks y el async-await, aunque parezca mucho, vale la pena que te tomes el tiempo necesario para aprender estos aspectos del lenguaje. Son herramientas sumamente valiosas y que te permiten seguir las mejores prácticas, pero requieren su tiempo de aprendizaje.

Comment: Me informaré sobre ello, ya que, por desgracia donde estudio, usamos practicas obsoletas en algunos aspectos, y yo, trabajando como becario ahora mismo, tengo bastantes dificultades a causa de ello, tomaré un par de fin de semanas para informarme sobre ello ya que desconocía su existencia completamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Un consejito, si crees que la consulta a la base de dato se va a llevar algo de tiempo (uno o dos segundos), yo creo que sería bueno que "deshabilitaras" el control que manda llamar a la consulta, por ejemplo, antes del "textbox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => ObtenerEstado());" poner un "controlItem.Enabled = false" y después poner un "controlItem.Enabled = true", ya que el usuario podría hacer click varias veces.

Comment: Uhm, por ahora lo tengo con threads, cuando tenga tiempo libre me documentaré sobre Tasks y las expresiones lamda y intentaré pasarlo, lo que he hecho por ahora es un apaño con if a la hora de iniciar el hilo, si el hilo está corriendo no se puede repetir, y después de la consulta (por si tarda) puse un thread.sleep. Opté por seguir con los threads ya que la aplicacion es algo "urgente", cuando sea operativa haré una segunda versión para mejorarla.

Answer (score 1):

> Sé que esta no es la solución más idonea, pero es la que,
>   temporalmente, voy a usar y me gustaría adjuntarla ya que, al menos
>   para mí, es más sencilla de entender.

Primeramente he añadido una clase con atributo estado y nombre, para poder identificar de que es el proceso en caso de necesitarlo a la hora de debugear.

```
class Estado
{
    private String estado;
    private String nombre;


    public Estado(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado)
    {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    public String getEstado()
    {
        return this.estado;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }

}
```

En el mismo Thread, creo el objeto `Estado xxxx = new Estado("Nombre del programa a monitorizar")`

Después, en la `Class hilos` creo el objeto de tipo estado.

```
class Hilos
    {

        public static Estado nombre;

        public static void mainthread() {


            nombre = new Estado("Viva la pizza con piña"); //por ejemplo

            //Creamos la conexión con la BBDD


            data=//Aquí iría una consulta MySQL
            Thread.Sleep(3000); //Tres segundos por si acaso, mejor prevenir que curar

            if(data==xxxx){
              nombre.setEstado("Activo");

            }else if(data==yyyy){
              nombre.setEstado("Suspendido");

            }else{
              nombre.setEstado("Detenido");

            }                

     }

}
```

Al ser el objeto publico, puedo usarlo desde la clase Form1 donde simplemente hago.

```
if(nombre.getEstado().contains("Activo"){
     textbox1.text = "Activo";

 }
```

> **Repito que esta solucion no es la más idonea, tan solo la pongo, por que es la que se me ha ocurrido y en motivos de tiempo me resultaba
>   más cómodo.**
>   También la adjunto por si alguien ve algo que pueda mejorar en el código, para que me diga (si no es molestia) y pueda mejorar. Un saludo.